# Why are GPS data inaccurate in urban areas?

Tags: android, ios, gps, geolocation

When I went to New York city for a business trip, I was testing my Android application that has GPS settings on it to see how accurate it was. The results that I got, was completely inaccurate. If I was in one building on the side of the street, the GPS would show that my device is on the opposite end of the street, in another building. I've tested on my iPhone just to make sure that it wasn't my application causing this, and to my surprise, it wasn't. Both devices showed me at the wrong location.

Is there a reason for this? The only reason I could think of is that the GPS satellite signals get messed up around tall buildings.

Is there a possible way to fix it? I'm guessing there is because of so many GPS applications for urban travel. How did they go about fixing it? I am genuinely curious.

Thank you so much.

Comment: no there is no way to fix poor GPS signal

Comment: Not sure this would be a complete answer, but basically, large amounts of metal interferes dramatically with GPS signal. It always seems to me that GPS is more accurate when I'm moving, so it's possible that Google Maps has algorithms to help smooth out the signal while moving, and that it's harder to get enough data points when you're standing still. But that's just completely theoretical on my part. I don't know any way to get a more accurate GPS signal, other than by using something like GPS Status and waiting until you have enough satellite signals.

Comment: Thank you guys. Camdroid, that would explain so much if you are right. I will wait for a definite answer before concluding my question. Thanks again for replying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New York is one of the cities with so called "Urban Canyons".
They have high buildings shielding the view to the sky, such that few satellites are visible, often not enough remain in view.

Second these building reflect the GPS signal which slightly delay the receiving, fooling the GPS chip, which then gives a wrong position.

if you compare applications make sure they all run in the same phone, and they record the locations at the same time.

> > How did they go about fixing it?

There is no fix for the urban canyon problem, besides using a better device.

**Update:**
Some GPS receivers, today, even used in smart phones, are "combined receivers".
They combine the US GPS System with (e.g) the Russian GLONASS, giving roughly the double number of visible satellites.
This approach significantly improves the accuracy within cities.

Comment: Theoretically, turning on WiFi should help with accuracy as it can look at signal strength of surrounding networks to help further triangulate its location. On iOS this is done on the OS level, so you won't have to do anything special.

Comment: I heavily doubt that IOS GPS locations are  improved by Wifi: The height attribute maybe. Do you have any document that decribes that iOS improves GPS by wifi, in case maximum accuracy is set?

Comment: From Apple: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201357 or for a little more explanation: http://www.quora.com/Why-is-location-accuracy-improved-when-wi-fi-is-enabled

Comment: Thanks for the document: The Apple doc is correct in its info, they tell that you get a faster  initial position using Wifi, using A-GPS. But not better once you have GPS!. (faster but not better!) The other link from quora.com is in my oppinion not correct info. While the indoor info is correct, it is wrong that wifi locations are better outddors. If one claims that, then they should provide a scientfic document with measures of the average number of meters offset from truth postion.